# Remove XML namespace attributes before converting to JSON

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, python-xmlschema

I'm converting an XML file to JSON. Namespace attributes in XML are also created in JSON file. How to remove that namespaces before converting XML to JSON?

Below is my xml code

```
<exta>
<sure>This </signature>
<begin_date>2019-07-12T09:41:48.187</begin_date>
<ver>4</ver>
<maiden_bc>1549</maiden_bc>
<exta_id>12345</exta_id>
<nps_max_price xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <exta_id>72723</exta_id>
    <extended_datetime>2018-11-20T11:01:29.040</extended_datetime>
    <event_ind>E</event_ind>
    <maiden>12345</maiden>
    <patient_id>123</patient_id>
    <boss_id>123LHF</boss_id>
    <template_name />
    <end_date>2019-01-01T00:00:00</end_date>
    <UYI_AMN xsi:nil="true" />
    <dedt_bef_ATS xsi:nil="true" />
    <form>W</form>
```

expected xml is:

```
<exta>
<sure>This </signature>
<begin_date>2019-07-12T09:41:48.187</begin_date>
<ver>4</ver>
<maiden_bc>1549</maiden_bc>
<exta_id>12345</exta_id>
<nps_max_price>
    <exta_id>72723</exta_id>
    <extended_datetime>2018-11-20T11:01:29.040</extended_datetime>
    <event_ind>E</event_ind>
    <maiden>12345</maiden>
    <patient_id>123</patient_id>
    <boss_id>123LHF</boss_id>
    <template_name />
    <end_date>2019-01-01T00:00:00</end_date>
    <UYI_AMN/>
    <dedt_bef_ATS/>
    <form>W</form>
```

my code to convert xml to json is:

```py
for datafile in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="test/"):

    if "xml" in datafile.key:
        # converting xml to json
        xml_file = datafile.get()['Body']
        print(datafile.get()['Body'])
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        xml_data = tree.getroot()
        xmlstr = ET.tostring(xml_data, encoding='utf-8', method='xml')
        data_dict = dict(xmltodict.parse(xmlstr, attr_prifix=''))
        json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
```

How to remove namespaces before I parse xml? Please help.

Comment: what namespace are you talking about, what exactly do  you want to remove from  xml

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar i want to remove ' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' & ' xsi:nil="true" /'

Comment: is it solved or you still need answer? I have the solution for this

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I'm still looking for solution, for temporary i used .replace('','') it worked but looks bad

Comment: If you are using lxml, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73005410/407651