# cleanup_namespaces does not remove namespaces from XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

Here is my xml string

```
xml = '''
<exta>
<signature>This </signature>
<begin_date>2019-07-12T09:41:48.187</begin_date>
<ver>4</ver>
<maiden_bc>1549</maiden_bc>
<exta_id>12345</exta_id>
<nps_max_price xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <exta_id>72723</exta_id>
    <extended_datetime>2018-11-20T11:01:29.040</extended_datetime>
    <event_ind>E</event_ind>
    <maiden>12345</maiden>
    <patient_id>123</patient_id>
    <boss_id>123LHF</boss_id>
    <template_name/>
    <end_date>2019-01-01T00:00:00</end_date>
    <UYI_AMN xsi:nil="true"/>
    <dedt_bef_ATS xsi:nil="true"/>
    <form>W</form>
</nps_max_price>
</exta>
'''
```

I was using `cleanup_namespaces` to remove namespace from the xml string

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
for elem in root.getiterator():
    elem.tag = etree.QName(elem).localname

etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
print(etree.tostring(root).decode())
```

This gives me :

```
<exta>
<signature>This </signature>
<begin_date>2019-07-12T09:41:48.187</begin_date>
<ver>4</ver>
<maiden_bc>1549</maiden_bc>
<exta_id>12345</exta_id>
<nps_max_price xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <exta_id>72723</exta_id>
    <extended_datetime>2018-11-20T11:01:29.040</extended_datetime>
    <event_ind>E</event_ind>
    <maiden>12345</maiden>
    <patient_id>123</patient_id>
    <boss_id>123LHF</boss_id>
    <template_name/>
    <end_date>2019-01-01T00:00:00</end_date>
    <UYI_AMN xsi:nil="true"/>
    <dedt_bef_ATS xsi:nil="true"/>
    <form>W</form>
</nps_max_price>
</exta>
```

However the expected output was xml to not to have the namespaces `xmlns:xsi, xsi:nil, xsd etc`. How can I do this?

**Expected Output:**

```
<exta>
<signature>This </signature>
<begin_date>2019-07-12T09:41:48.187</begin_date>
<ver>4</ver>
<maiden_bc>1549</maiden_bc>
<exta_id>12345</exta_id>
<nps_max_price>
    <exta_id>72723</exta_id>
    <extended_datetime>2018-11-20T11:01:29.040</extended_datetime>
    <event_ind>E</event_ind>
    <maiden>12345</maiden>
    <patient_id>123</patient_id>
    <boss_id>123LHF</boss_id>
    <template_name/>
    <end_date>2019-01-01T00:00:00</end_date>
    <UYI_AMN/>
    <dedt_bef_ATS/>
    <form>W</form>
</nps_max_price>
</exta>
```

Comment: Per [lxml docs](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#cleanup_namespaces), `cleanup_namespaces` does not entirely remove all namespaces but unused ones: *Remove all namespace declarations from a subtree that are not used by any of the elements or attributes in that tree.* The `xsi` namespace is being used.

Comment: You need to modify the tree, redefining elements without namespace either with XPath loops or my preference, XSLT 1.0, which lxml supports. Research and give it an earnest attempt. Good luck!

Comment: You need to decide what to do with the xsi:nil attributes before you drop the namespace.

Comment: wdym? what I want to do, I mean I don't want to do anything with it

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar what is the result that you want, and why do you want it?

Comment: I just want namespaces to be removed from xml, eg `xmlns:xsi:[], xsi: []`.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar can you please edit the question to include a new code block that shows the XML result that you want, and explain why do you want it? What are you trying to achieve by removing namespaces?

Comment: I don't think it should matter why I want to remove it, however upodating the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question removes namespaces from *elements*. But in your XML string, none of the elements are bound to a namespace. That is why nothing changes.

However, there are two namespaced *attributes* (`xsi:nil`). If you simply want to delete those attributes (or any namespaced attribute), here is how you can do it:

```
for elem in root.iter():      
    for attr in elem.attrib:
        if etree.QName(attr).namespace:
            del elem.attrib[attr]

etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
```

Comment: And what about `xmlns:xsi` does the code remove it as well?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "none of the elements are bound to a namespace. "

Comment: I mean exactly what I say. None of the elements in the XML are bound to (belong to) a namepace. You only have attributes bound to a namespace. When the two `xsi:nil` attributes are removed, `etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)` will remove the `xmlns:xsi="..."` declaration, since the namespace is no longer used.

Comment: Side note: I used `iter()` since `getiterator()` is deprecated: https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#getiterator.